# why do we need attribute grammar in semantic analysis?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, semantics

I am currently reading a [book](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) about compiler construction. In chapter 4 it spends a lot of space talking about attribute grammar, which confuses me a lot.

**Why do we need it? and how is it used in production compiler?**

[image]

It seems to me that attribute grammar is used to decorate a parse tree into abstract syntax tree. But why can't we build ASTs in the parsing phase?

For example, in OCaml, I can describe AST like this:

```
type ast =
  | Var of string
  | Num of int
  | If of test * then * else
  ...
  ...
```

To build an if node, I can simply do `If (test, then, else)`

Comment: It is indeed no hard requirement that you _must_ use an attributed grammar and/or an AST in your compiler. It's just a common way of doing things.

Comment: Regarding your question on " why cant we build STs in the parsing phase?" .During parsing we do construct AST and pass it to the Semantic analyser.The semantic analyser adds some more information to the nodes of tha AST(for example its type,value etc) which cant be added during syntax phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote a lot of different compilers you might get tired of reproducing the same sorts of code over and over again. Things like attribute grammars reduce the amount of boilerplate coding by moving some obvious things into the grammar definition.

You can ask the same question about systems like yacc--why not just write code to do the parsing? The answer is that after writing a few compilers you get tired of it and start wanting some higher-level help.

Another advantage is that (if the system is implemented correctly), you avoid the opportunity to make errors in your boilerplate code.

Comment: Is there any simple compiler somewhere online that use attribute grammar? The book I am reading contains a lot of theory that I think some sample code may help me.

Comment: You might try looking at the code samples at the companion site for the book: http://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124104099/ Supposedly they have been extended into full runnable programs. I don't know of any specific compilers using attribute grammars--sorry.